# In reward-and-punishment system, what is the meaning of curses?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, mitzvah, curse, ki-tavo

In Sefer Dvorim the Torah does not spare curses for general misbehaving or misbelieving, etc. In my understanding, the Torah presents a clear system of reward and punishment (Rambam's principles) - do a Mitzvah and you get rewarded, do a sin and you're punished ([Ki Tavo for example](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.28.30?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=en&aliyot=0)).

> **All these curses shall befall you; they shall pursue you and overtake you, until you are wiped out, because you did not heed the LORD your God and keep the commandments and laws that He enjoined upon you**. They shall serve as signs and proofs against you and your offspring for all time. Because you would not serve the LORD your God in joy and gladness over the abundance of everything, you shall have to serve—in hunger and thirst, naked and lacking everything—the enemies whom the LORD will let loose against you. He will put an iron yoke upon your neck until He has wiped you out.
>
> The LORD will bring a nation against you from afar, from the end of the earth, which will swoop down like the eagle—a nation whose language you do not understand, a ruthless nation, that will show the old no regard and the young no mercy.
>
> It shall devour the offspring of your cattle and the produce of your soil, until you have been wiped out, leaving you nothing of new grain, wine, or oil, of the calving of your herds and the lambing of your flocks, until it has brought you to ruin.
>
> It shall shut you up in all your towns throughout your land until every mighty, towering wall in which you trust has come down.

What part do those general and unrelated to specific Mitzvos curses play in our reward-and-punishment Mitzvos system?

NB: Please don't bring Kabbole saying all those are Brochos, we just don't know how to read it properly.

Comment: Specific punishments for specific mitzvos, general punishments for a general lax/careless/contemptuous attitude towards mitzvos. I'm not sure I'm seeing what the question is. Also see Rambam, Hilchos Teshuvah ch. 9.

Comment: So it's natural if while speeding you pay the fine twice - one for speeding and one for being careless? Rambam says there are no "general" Mitzvos, no Mitzvos no punishment - isn't it logical?

Comment: If a person is speeding and also is disrespectful to the officer who pulls them over, then yes, they'll get penalized twice - a fine and (probably) jail. I don't know what you mean by your second sentence: the Rambam says in Sefer Hamitzvos that "general" statements (שמור את כל המצוה, for example) don't count among the 613, but he surely agrees that they're binding.

Comment: @Meir Binding and punishable are two different things. THis is a very dangerous slope - you can be fined for speeding but not for being not nice or gloomy to policemen.

Comment: First of all, Al, there's a vast difference between being "not nice or gloomy" vs. belligerent. Second, I don't know what Israeli cops are like, but here in America there have been various unfortunate incidents where the cop didn't like the driver's attitude and reacted violently, so I wouldn't recommend testing it. But third, and most important, the comparison is flawed, because Hashem is the One who made the rules and who created us, neither of which is true of the police officer.

Comment: @AlBerko the Rambam of course believes in general obligations. He doesn't believe that R Samlai's number of 613 double-counts by numbering both the individual mitzvos and umbrellas that include them.

Comment: @MichaBerger Please continue to reconcile. The Torah says "תחת אשר לא ... בשמחה" - is that an obligation to be punished so severely for? Where does Rambam mention that for not performing Mizvos joyfully *in general,* the nation would be so harshly punished?

Comment: @AlBerko: A husband and father betrays his (innocent) family by breaking the seventh commandment. This, in turn, might have medical repercussions on his own physical body, which, subsequently, could potentially afflict the rest of his household, both financially (to cure oneself) and medically (if the contracted illness is transmissible).

Comment: @AlBerko: But this new question has nothing to do with what's a mitzvah, but why Hashem would punish us for not being happy with the mitzvos we do. Because that's in the Torah, regardless of the Rambam and whether he would call that happiness obligatory or whether he would count it among the 613 .

Comment: @AlBerko: in any case, Chazal cal it "tokhakhah" for a reason. While Hashem calls it a qalala, thus your question, chazal see it as a warning against doing something wrong.